# Tratar exception no retorno do Ajax jsonp

Tags: ajax, jsonp

Pesssoal estou fazendo a chamada do serviço dessa maneira:

```
$.ajax({
    url: minhaurl,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    success: function (result, status, request) {
        console.log('sucesso');
    },
    error: function (request, status, erro) {
        console.log('sucesso');
    }
});
```

Quando recebo sucesso do serviço o retorno esperado é json igual a este:

```
callback({"d":{"Mensagem":"","Id":"1000","DDD":"0011","Telefone":"999999999","Fax":"999999999","Flag1":true,"Segmento":"A","Horario_diferenciado":null,"Caixa_exclusivo":"1","CaixaEletronico":null,"Nome":"Nome da agencia","Endereco":"Rua A","Cep":"09050-380","Uf":"SP","Cidade":"SAO PAULO","Bairro":"PQ BANDEIRANTE","Abertura":"10h:00","Fechamento":"16h:00","Longitude":-46.641869,"Latitude":-23.634659,"Imagem":"icone.png"}});
```

Quando recebo erro do serviço o retorno é esse:

```
callback({"Message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","StackTrace":"   at Banco.WS.BuscadorAgencias.BuscaAgenciaPorNumero()","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException"});
```

O problema é que mesmo escrevendo success e error, quando ocorre o erro não consigo tratá-lo.

No console do browser aparece o erro:

> jquery-1.11.3.js:9836  GET
>   minhaurl&callback=jQuery111306013578134038797_1477314780144&_=1477314780145

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver este problema colocando um timeout na chamada do ajax. 
Infelizmente não consegui de nenhuma outra forma.

Aparentemente quando meu serviço retorna uma exception o jquery se perde e não consegue desmontar os dados do callback.

Colocando o timeout na função ajax consegui cair no catch e exibir minha mensagem.